# How to use email preview together with catch all route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

If I add a catch all route in my routes file I cannot anymore access the email preview paths because they are appended to the routes and there fore defined after my catch all route.

How to solve this so that I can use email preview and have catch all route?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add these routes in your routes.rb before the catch all route.

```
get '/rails/mailers'         => "rails/mailers#index"
get '/rails/mailers/*path'   => "rails/mailers#preview"
```